# Refused to display in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, content-security-policy, owasp

I am developing a salesforce app which is rendered inside an iframe in salesforce page.  Using node express server to render this page. As part of security review, i want to render only in salesforce page and block if embedded anywhere else.

For that, i have added content-security-policy header as below:

`response.header("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors salesforce.com");`

But it is blocked on salesforce page too.

Error :

> Refused to display 'https://localhost:8000/authenticate' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors salesforce.com".*

salesforce app url where my iframe is rendering : https://ap4.salesforce.com/0016F00001vmoMu

I tried giving domain as `*.salesforce.com` in directives. But it didn't work either.

Can someone help me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a subdomain e.g. subdomain.salesforce.com?

Comment: salesforce app url : https://ap4.salesforce.com/0016F00001vmoMu
I tried to give domain as *.salesforce.com still not lucky

Comment: Maybe the policy inherits the used port. I would give this a try -> https://*.salesforce.com:*  If this doesn't help, I'd double-check the DOM in your browser's developer tools, to see the ancestor tree.

Comment: We have to add response header : X-Frame-Options.
I have added in Nginx before serving response to client:
add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://ap8.salesforce.com/";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting this policy enabled it to render in all browsers

```
 add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-src 'self' https://salesforce.com;"
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove https and add subdomain like

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-src 'self' www.salesforce.com;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this trying to open a full page in a frame, the fix was the target attribute for the  tag e.g. <a target="_top" ...

[w3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)