# How to use CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS header in Django project?

Tags: django, iframe, django-csp

I'm looking to load a [Django site](https://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com/) of my design into an iframe. For this, I added the following lines in my Django settings.py file:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
          ...
    'csp.middleware.CSPMiddleware', 
        ...
]

            . . .
CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ("'self'", 'localhost:*')
```

So that I can load my site from any address of my localhost. However, when I load my site at the following url:`http://localhost:3000/searchEngine` I get in the devtools inspector the following error:

```
 Refused to frame 'https://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' localhost:*".
```

I tried to find the solution on this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781949/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-an-ancestor-violates-the-following-content), on this [blog](https://www-digitalocean-com.translate.goog/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-django-application-with-a-content-security-policy?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=sc), also on another [blog](https://www-geeksforgeeks-org.translate.goog/adding-csp-headers-in-django-project/?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=sc) on the internet and again on this [blog](https://www.laac.dev/blog/content-security-policy-using-django/) and tried to replace `CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS`  by  `CSP_FRAME_SRC` like this:

```
CSP_FRAME_SRC = ["'self'", 'localhost:*'] #instead of CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ("'self'", 'localhost:*')
```

but that didn't solve the problem and the header was even ignored. I also tried to fix this by changing my setting to `CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS` like this:

```
CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ("'self'", 'http://localhost:3000/searchEngine')
```

Now I get the following error:

```
Refused to frame 'https://gkwhelps.herokuapp.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' http://localhost:3000/searchEngine".
```

I don't know where my fault is. Yet, I defined exactly the port `3000` and the route `searchEngine` used by the localhost to contain the site in the iframe.