# Visualforce page with Stripe payment intent page is not working in iPhone and Mac

Tags: iphone, browser, stripe-payments, salesforce, visualforce

I have a Visualforce Page on which I am creating the Stript Payment intent page via Stripe API callout.

The callout is returning the payment page (Name, Card detail, etc input fields).

The page is working on Android, windows, and Mac (chrome browser), but it's not showing anything on iPhone and Mac Safari Browser.

For Stripe Callout I am using **//js.stripe.com/v3/** libreary

Below is the error I am getting on inspect element in iPhone Browser:

- *ComponentProfiler: Component-level profiling has not been enabled because "componentProfiler.instrumentation.ltng" gate is not open.*
- *because it does not appear in the frame-ancestors directive of the Content Security Policy.*

I have tried the solutions provided below articles:

- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262697/content-security-policy-error-while-loading-apex-iframe
- [Refused to display in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781949/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-an-ancestor-violates-the-following-content)

Comment: Can you provide more details? Things like the full console output from Safari, details from the Network tab in the dev tools in Safari, the relevant code, and a link to a reduced test case would be extremely helpful.